# Submitting HTML form to change url in django

Tags: django, forms

I am developing a price comparison site using `Django 1.6` that now I am working on conversation of currency. Now my url pattern is as below:

```
http://www.example.com/product_search/123123123/currency
```

`123123123` is the UID for the product. When user typed `http://www.example.com/product_search/123123123/USD`, the product price will be changed to `USD` and `http://www.example.com/product_search/123123123/NZD` will change the currency to `NZD`. I can do the currency conversion by changing the URL without problem.

The next step is the create a form in my html template that user select his/her preferred currency, by clicking submit, the currency parameter of the link will be changed accordingly and show the product price with preferred currency.

I created my html template (part of) as below:

```
<form action='' class='sky-form' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-10">
                <label class="select">
                    <select name="Currency">
                        {% for currency_dict in currency_dict_qs %}
                            <option value="{{currency_dict.currency_code}}" {% with price_output_qs.all|first as price_output %}{% if price_output.product_currency_mod == currency_dict.currency_code %}selected{% endif %}{% endwith %}>
                                {{currency_dict.currency_name}} - {{currency_dict.currency_code}}
                            </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <i></i>
                </label>
            </section>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I think I am seriously lack of knowledge on knowing how Django interacts with HTML forms. I tried the official document but it seems to complicated to me. Can anyone inspire me a bit by give some example so that I can follow and understand the concepts afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building the form yourself, not using the [Form API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) in Django, what you can do is getting the HTML select value in your view, using the `currency = request.POST.get('Currency', None)` then redirect the URL to `http://www.example.com/product_search/123123123/currency`.

Don't forget to run some checks on the value you got from the POST before redirecting to the URL.